# LD_LIBRARY_PATH in Conda environment

Tags: python, conda, distutils

I create a Conda environment (**myenv**), and build a Python extension (using `distutils`) in this env.
My library uses some libraries which exist on both `/usr/local/lib` and `/home/user/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib`.

In **myenv**, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is empty, but `ldd mylib.so` shows that my library links to libraries in `/home/user/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib`.
This makes sense but I wonder why it doesn't link to libraries in `/usr/local/lib`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that path
`$ORIGIN/../lib` was set in RPATH of python in myenv.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you're using the compiler and related toolchain from your conda environment. This toolchain is set up to use the libraries from your conda environment automatically.

Comment: No gcc/g++ in Conda.

Comment: How did you verify? `conda env export | grep gcc`? Did you check both `myenv` and the base environment?

Comment: - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=main
  - libgcc-ng=9.1.0=hdf63c60_0

Comment: which gcc --> /usr/bin/gcc